# Can't access files in ESXi 6.0 datastore

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter, bacula

I am trying to get backups running again in an ESXi 6.0 system. They were running prior to my tenure, but stopped. I am using a fresh install of vCenter on Windows Server 2012 I'm stuck on what seems to be a privileges problem even though the backup user has full Administrator privileges (temporarily).  I've been told that the privileges work differently when accessing the datastore, but I don't know why. Where can I go to learn the details of datastore access privileges?

vddk: vddk.c:1239-0 ERROR: Can't open [datastore1] machinename/machinename-000002.vmdk.
vddk: vddk.c:1240-0 VIXERROR: You do not have access rights to this file

Answer (score 0):

The answer had nothing to do with the datastore privileges, not directly at least. The bacula service provider was accessing the machine via it's IP address not it's FQDN! As soon as they corrected their configuration files the problem disappeared. Phew! I was beginning to think that I was going nutz...